# How can I losslessly convert .webp images to .png?

Tags: conversion, png, image-formats, webp

I have a bunch of .webp images that I want to convert to .png. How can I do that without introducing any loss? GUI or CLI doesn't matter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The challenge here is in not discarding any transparency that may exist in your original .webp file.

If you use Microsoft Paint, which is both able to open WebP images and save PNG files, it will give you the following warning when you try to save it as a PNG file:

[image]

In order to preserve any transparency, you would either need to use an application such as Photoshop or GIMP, or an online tool such as [this](https://ezgif.com/webp-to-png).

Comment: Also [GIMP](https://www.gimp.org/) (a free "Photoshop") can [save transparency](https://sirarsalih.com/2018/04/23/how-to-make-background-transparent-in-gimp/)

Answer (score 2):

On Linux based systems, depending on your distro, install [libwebp](https://repology.org/project/libwebp/versions) package.

Then converting is as easy as:

```
➜ dwebp P1.webp -o P1.png
Decoded P1.webp. Dimensions: 25 x 24 . Format: lossless. Now saving...
Saved file P1.png
```

Comment: I use this in my workflow nowadays instead of GIMP/photoshop to convert 100s upon 100s of WebPs at once! thanks for sharing :)